# Finding center of rotation

Tags: matrices

I know how to find the center of rotation and degree of rotation by using geometry. However, I  have seen that if I draw perpendicular line through the line connecting two points on different places on the line, different center of rotation is derived. 
I hope this clears it up.

So I want to know if there can be more than one possible center of rotation or if my procedure is wrong.

Also I want to know if there is a way to find the center of rotation by calculation. I study in class-8 so please be easy on me. Thank You
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCEeB.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what to make of your description. What line do you call "the line" for instance? In the picture you attached, the point $C$ seems to be the center of rotation. If you mean to say that the intersection of the fat black lines would be one as well, that doesn't seem to be the case.

If, as your picture suggestst, you're interested in triangles, we can say the following: you have two congruent triangles in a plane where one can't be transformed in the other by a translation, there will be a unique rotation (i.e. center of rotation and corresponding angle) moving one into the other.

Why is that? Just using your naming, one triangle is called $PQR$ and the other $P'Q'R'$. If there is a center of rotation $C$, we know that $CP=CP'$ as well as $CQ=CQ'$. The point $C$ therefore has to lie on the line bisecting $PP'$ as well as on the line bisecting $QQ'$. These lines have a unique intersection, so there cannot be more than one center of rotation.

However, nothing like this holds for shapes that aren't triangles. Let us just consider a real plane with standard coordinates on it. And suppose there are two triangles with radius one, one having center $(1,1)$ and one having center $(-1,1)$. One can be obtained from the other by rotation around $(0,1)$ with $180$ degrees, but also by rotation around $(0,0)$ with rotation by $90$ degrees. As a matter of fact, you can obtain one circle from the other by rotation around any point on the $y$-axis.

So what I think is your question can be answered by: it depends entirely on the shape of the object how many possible rotations there are to obtain one from the other.